# Distribution of Last Passage Percolation on $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Tags: probability, queueing-theory, percolation

Suppose I have  square lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and I endow each site $x$ with a weight $W_x$, which is an independent exponential random variable of rate $\mu$.  An oriented path  between $(1, 1)$ and a point $(M, N)$, with $M,N\geq{}1$ is called increasing if it only ever goes in the North and East directions. Define the weight of an increasing path $\pi$ to be

$W(\pi) = \sum_{x\in\pi}W_x$

and the passage time, $T(M,N)$, from $(1, 1)$ to $(M, N)$ to be the maximum of $W(\pi)$ over the possible increasing paths. My question is, what is the distribution of $T(M,N)$? So far everything I can find only considers limits for large $M,N$ but I'm interested in the distribution for a fixed $M,N$.

Comment: Do you mean that $W_x$ has exponential distribution with rate $\mu_x$, as opposed to a constant rate $\mu$ for all $x$?

Comment: Nope, I'm only considering the special case where all the rates are constant.

Comment: Since $W_x$ is the same for all states, isn't $W(\pi)$ for every $\pi$ equal to the sum of $M - 1 + N - 1$ exponential random variables with parameter $\mu$, i.e. an Erlang distribution with parameters $M - 1 + N - 1$ and $\mu$? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you ar missing the taking the maximum over paths parts. There are $M+N-2$ choose $M-1$ paths and we take the maximum over these. $W(\pi)$ aren't independent.